# How can I return all functions defined within a function?

Tags: r, function, environment-variables, return-value

I want to return all functions I have defined within a function.

I know ls() can be used to return names of my functions, but I need to return a list of the functions defined in the original function's body.

For example, my function might look like

```
primaryFunction<-function(){
    a<-function(){return (2)} 
    b<-function(){return (3)} 
    return(?)}
```

where return(?) is supposed to return a list containing the functions a,b.

Comment: I fixed some of the errors in the sample code as pointed out by Konrad Rudolph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I’d list them all separately to be explicit:

```
primary_function = function () {
    a = function () 2
    b = function () 3
    list(a = a, b = b)
}
```

But you can abbreviate if there are many:

```
primary_function = function () {
    a = function () 2
    b = function () 3
    as.list(environment())
}
```

(You could also return the environment itself instead of copying it into a list.)

Note that this will return *all* local symbols. If you have non-function symbols and want to return only functions, instead do

```
primary_function = function () {
    a = function () 2
    b = function () 3
    mget(lsf.str())
}
```

Also note that your code contains errors since in R `return` isn’t a statement, it’s a *function call*, which aborts the current function execution. As such, you need to write it with parentheses (e.g. `return(2)`, not `return 2`), and their use is redundant here: R always returns the last value of a function’s execution. That’s why I omitted them. I only use `return` to signal an early exit.